# changing text after regular interval

Tags: javascript

I want to write a code that takes up a paragraph  and the contents of the paragraph are changed at certain intervals say 5 seconds.the contents should alternate at every 5 seconds. using javascript.here is my attempt.

```
<html>
<script>
    i = 0;

    function changeText(txt) {
            var s = txt;
            document.body.innerHTML.change = document.body.innerHTML.replace(s, Mudit ");
                replaceorig(txt); i++;
                if (i % 2 == 0) setTimeOut(function() {
                    changeText();
                }, 500);
            }

            function replaceorig(txt) {
                document.body.innerHTML.change = txt;
            }
</script>

<body onload="changeText('My name is Mudit')" ;>
    <p id="change">My name is Mudit</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There seems to be some syntax-error at .replace(s, Mudit ");

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0;

function changeText(txt) {
    var s = txt;
    document.body.getElementById("change").innerHTML = document.body.getElementById("change").innerHTML.replace(s, "Mudit");
    replaceorig(txt);
    i++;
    if (i % 2 == 0) setTimeOut(function() {
        changeText();
    }, 5000);
}

function replaceorig(txt) {
    document.body.getElementById("change").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

This fixes all errors in the code:

- `document.body.innerHTML.change` is not the correct way to address the p-element.
- `500` is 500 milliseconds, or half a second, so you need `5000`.
- `Mudit` wasn't properly quoted in the replace function.

There are still a few issues I couldn't solve, because I do not know what you want to do:

- `document.body.getElementById("change").innerHTML = document.body.getElementById("change").innerHTML.replace(s, "Mudit");` This line will replace the text with your name `Mudit`, but will be immediately overwritten by `replaceorig(txt);`
- After five seconds `changeText` is called via the `setTimeout` but doesn't provide an argument. So the `p-element` will be set to `undefined` every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, I made a function that takes an element which's text should be modified, texts that should be used successively and a time in milliseconds:

```
function changeText(element, texts, time) {

  var text = texts.splice(0, 1) [0];
  if (text) {
    element.innerHTML = text;
    setTimeout(function () {
      changeText(element, texts, time);
    }, time);
  }

}

var element = document.body.getElementById("change");
var texts = [
  'My name is Mudit',
  'my name is joe',
  'my name is johnson',
  'my name is jack'
];
var time = 5000;

changeText(element, texts, time);
```